# Linq to Objects where clause and typecasting

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have the following:

```
class BaseType {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}

class Option : BaseType {
  public String DisplayName { get; set; }
  public String StoredValue { get; set; }
}

class Container {
  public Collection<BaseType> Options;
}


Container c = new Container();
c.Options.add(new Option() { Id=1, DisplayName="Bob", StoredValue="aaaa"});
c.Options.add(new Option() { Id=2, DisplayName="Dora", StoredValue="bbbb"});
c.Options.add(new Option() { Id=3, DisplayName="Sara", StoredValue="cccc"});
```

Now, what I want to do is pull out the DisplayName of the specific option that matches StoredValue.

Previously, I'd iterate over the entire collection until I found a match.  But, I'd rather have something that looked a bit better...

I got started with

```
var found = (from c in c.Options
             where ...
```

And that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
c.Options.OfType<Option>()
 .Where(o => o.StoredValue == "aaaa")
 .Select(o => o.DisplayName)
 .SingleOrDefault();  //or .ToList()
```

Comment: That is a bad answer, if you have any other type it will blowup.

Comment: @CrazyDart: nothing a simple check can't fix, as now added to the code.

Comment: the check is fine (and works) but you just reimplemented OfType<> inside your lambas -- twice.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want: (`Single` will error if 0 or more than 1 match is found)

```
string searchValue = "aaaa";
string displayName = c.Options.OfType<Option>.Single(o => o.StoredValue == searchValue).DisplayName;
```

Or to allow for multiple values: (this will give you all the display names that match, 0 to many)

```
IEnumerable<string> displayNames = from o in c.Options.OfType<Option>
                                   where o.StoredValue == searchValue
                                   select o.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Oh, now I see why it was confusing you in the first place!  I've fixed the code using the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension, which filters the Options list to `Option` types without making you write the logic for it (and introduce bugs, like the other answers have).

Answer (score 2):

```
var found = (from c in c.Options.OfType<Option>()
             where c.StoredValue == yourValue
             select c.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using Linqpad.  You need to cast as the Option type first, then you can use it.  I put in a check to find all of that type then check for the value.

```
void Main()
{
    Container c = new Container();
    c.Options.Add(new Option() { Id=1, DisplayName="Bob", StoredValue="aaaa"});
    c.Options.Add(new Option() { Id=2, DisplayName="Dora", StoredValue="bbbb"});
    c.Options.Add(new Option() { Id=3, DisplayName="Sara", StoredValue="cccc"});

var t = from x in c.Options.OfType<Option>()
        where x.DisplayName == "Bob"
        select x.StoredValue;
t.Dump();

}

class BaseType {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}

class Option : BaseType {
  public String DisplayName { get; set; }
  public String StoredValue { get; set; }
}

class Container {
  public List<BaseType> Options;

  public Container() { Options = new List<BaseType>(); }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the container Options to using a List<>.  When I try this, it errors on the .OfType<Option> part.

Comment: Interesting, because it runs just fine on my system.

Comment: Okay, so I tried this exact code in a new project and that worked.  No idea why I get the squigglies under .OfType in the real project.  Interesting.

Comment: Figured out the problem.  I apparently can't read parenthesis correctly.  I was missing them after the .OfType<Option>